# Sum of squares knowing its ogf

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to get following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n^2}$$

While I know its ogf:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n x^n}$$

Any hint would be valuable.

Comment: If you know $a_n$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$ then what's stopping you from computing the sum of $a_n^2$? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I know $f(x)$ but not $a_n$ itself. For instance, if sum was not over squared terms its value would be $f(1)$

Comment: Hint: apply the Parseval identity to $f(\theta)=\sum_{n \geq 1}{a_ne^{in\theta}}$.

Comment: Thanks Mindlack, I did not realized but ogf does not belong to $L^2_{(-\pi,\pi]}$, so Parseval's identity seem not appliable in that case. My ofg is: $\frac{z}{ln(1+z)}$